# Snapshot Listener won't detach or stop in android studio firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, listener

I had tried the methods of detaching listeners like `ListenerRegistration` or adding the activity on the `addSnapshotListener` but neither of those works. I tried to delete some data in my database and it works fine but when I click the back button my app throws an error on the lines that are inside the Listener.

**EDIT:**
Just to make clear I tried to use the `ListenerRegistration` and the adding of the activity in `addSnapshotListener` separately and still not working.

```
ExpandedCartActivity

registration = query.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.e("DB_Error", e.toString());
                    return;
                }
                for (DocumentChange dc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = dc.getDocument();
                    BasketProductsModel basketProductsModelList = snapshot.toObject(BasketProductsModel.class);
                    Map<String, String> prodImage = basketProductsModelList.getProductImage();
                    String prodName = basketProductsModelList.getProductName();
                    double productPrice = basketProductsModelList.getProductPrice();
                    double productCuttedPrice = basketProductsModelList.getProductCuttedPrice();
                    String productID = basketProductsModelList.getProductID();
                    int productQuantity = basketProductsModelList.getProductQuantity();
                    boolean isBargain = (boolean) snapshot.get("bargain.bargainStatus");
                    int oldIndex = dc.getOldIndex();
                    int newIndex = dc.getNewIndex();

                    switch (dc.getType()) {
                        case ADDED:
                            if (isBargain) {
                                long discountValue = (long) snapshot.get("bargain.discountValue");
                                double discount = (double) discountValue;
                                double discountPoint = discount / 100;
                                double dp = productPrice * discountPoint;
                                double newPrice = productPrice - dp;
                                basketProducts.add(new BasketProductsModel(prodImage, prodName, productQuantity, productPrice, newPrice, productID, storeID, UserID));
                            } else {
                                basketProducts.add(new BasketProductsModel(prodImage, prodName, productQuantity, productPrice, productCuttedPrice, productID, storeID, UserID));
                            }
                            break;

                        case MODIFIED:
                            if (isBargain) {
                                long discountValue = (long) snapshot.get("bargain.discountValue");
                                double discount = (double) discountValue;
                                double discountPoint = discount / 100;
                                double dp = productPrice * discountPoint;
                                double newPrice = productPrice - dp;
                                basketProducts.set(newIndex, new BasketProductsModel(prodImage, prodName, productQuantity, productPrice, newPrice, productID, storeID, UserID));
                            } else {
                                basketProducts.set(newIndex, new BasketProductsModel(prodImage, prodName, productQuantity, productPrice, productCuttedPrice, productID, storeID, UserID));
                            }
                            break;

                        case REMOVED:
                            basketProducts.remove(oldIndex);
                            break;
                    }

                    final NumberFormat cf1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "PH"));

                    int prodQuantity = 0;
                    for (int r = 0; r < basketProducts.size(); r++) {
                        int prodQuan = basketProducts.get(r).getProductQuantity();
                        prodQuantity += prodQuan;
                    }

                    if (prodQuantity > 1) {
                        productquantityTotal.setText("Products: (" + prodQuantity + " items)");
                    } else {
                        productquantityTotal.setText("Product: (" + prodQuantity + " item)");
                    }
                    double subtotal = 0;
                    for (int d = 0; d < basketProducts.size(); d++) {
                        int prodQuan = basketProducts.get(d).getProductQuantity();
                        double pcp = basketProducts.get(d).getProductCuttedPrice();
                        double data = basketProducts.get(d).getProductPrice();

                        if (pcp == 0) {
                            double mult = data * prodQuan;
                            subtotal += mult;
                        } else {
                            double mult = pcp * prodQuan;
                            subtotal += mult;
                        }
                    }

                    coupon_text.setText("You are using coupon in this Order.");
                    button.setText("change");
                    redeem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7AC1FE"));
                    couponname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    coupondiscount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    final String productSubtotal = cf1.format(subtotal);
                    productPriceSubtotal.setText("Php " + productSubtotal);

                    final double finalSubtotal = subtotal;
                    db.collection("Baskets").document(UserID).collection("Store_Baskets").document(storeID).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                            if (e != null) {
                                Log.e("DB_Error", e.toString());
                            } else {
                                String couponId = documentSnapshot.get("couponID").toString();
                                if (couponId.equals("")) {
                                    couponname.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    coupondiscount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    saved.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    redeem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    productPriceSubtotal.setText(productSubtotal);
                                    totalamount.setText(productSubtotal);
                                } else {
                                    db.collection("Coupons").document(UserID).collection("Store_Coupons").document(couponId).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                                            if (e != null) {
                                                Log.e("DB_Error", e.toString());
                                            } else {
                                                CouponsModel model = documentSnapshot.toObject(CouponsModel.class);
                                                String couponType = model.getCouponType();
                                                int couponValue = model.getCouponValue();
                                                boolean isUsed = model.isUsed();

                                                if (!isUsed) {
                                                    if (couponType.equals("percent")) {
                                                        String couponVal = Integer.toString(couponValue);
                                                        coupondiscount.setText(couponVal + "% off");
                                                        double coupondouble = couponValue;
                                                        double percent = coupondouble / 100;
                                                        double Subtotalprice = finalSubtotal;
                                                        double discountedPrice = finalSubtotal * percent;
                                                        long rounded = Math.round(discountedPrice);
                                                        double TotalPrice = Subtotalprice - rounded;
                                                        String disPrice = cf1.format(rounded);
                                                        String ctotalprice = cf1.format(TotalPrice);
                                                        totalamount.setText(ctotalprice);
                                                        saved.setText("You will save " + disPrice + " on this Order");
                                                    } else if (couponType.equals("whole")) {
                                                        String couponVal = cf1.format(couponValue);
                                                        coupondiscount.setText(couponVal + " off");
                                                        double TotalPrice = finalSubtotal - couponValue;
                                                        String ctotalprice = cf1.format(TotalPrice);
                                                        totalamount.setText(ctotalprice);
                                                        saved.setText("You will save Php " + couponValue + " on this Order");
                                                    } else {
                                                        Log.e("DB_Error", "Coupon Data Error");
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
...

 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (registration!= null) {
            registration.remove();
            registration = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        baseAdapter.stopListening();
        if (registration!= null) {
            registration.remove();
            registration = null;
        }
    }
```

**Then here's the exception**

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.dreamakers.coonna.Activity.ExpandedCartActivity$3$1.onEvent(ExpandedCartActivity.java:353)
        at com.dreamakers.coonna.Activity.ExpandedCartActivity$3$1.onEvent(ExpandedCartActivity.java:347)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:541)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference$$Lambda$3.onEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ExecutorEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:42)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ExecutorEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

**Which was from:**

`String couponId = documentSnapshot.get("couponID").toString();`

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: In the line 97 sir

Comment: Which is? Please hightlight it in your question.